# ERC-2222 : Funds Distribution Token implementation for a fee contract

Tags: contract-development, erc-20, fees, inheritance, interfaces

My MainCore contract is a contract who sell NFT, and all the sell and buy have a 1% fee for team developper (uint DevelopperCutTotalSupply).

I try to implement the ERC-2222 "Funds Distribution Token (FDT)" to my contract (https://github.com/atpar/funds-distribution-token) to distribute claim fee power to each member of my team with weight according to importance on project.

So, I deploy the contract

```
contract FDT_ERC20Extension is IFundsDistributionToken, FundsDistributionToken {...}
```

Wich have the capacity to set a ERC20 contract, distribute % claim, withdrawn funds AND FDT_ERC20 Extension is a contract which pay the claim with ETHER.

So now I need to send ETHER to the FET-ERC20 Extension.

I can send with ether

```
interface IFundsDistributionTokenOptional {

/** 
 * @notice Deposits funds to this contract.
 * The deposited funds may be distributed to other accounts.
 */
function depositFunds() external payable;
```

But the DevelopperCutTotalSupply is on the MainCore contract, and the MainCore contract have All the Bid/sell/fee, but I want only DevelopperCutTotalSupply accessible for ERC-2222.

It's what I did :

```
contract MainCore is IFundsDistributionTokenOptional {
       function depositFunds(uint value) public payable {
        IFundsDistributionTokenOptional.depositFunds;}}
```

How to send ether with my MainCore contract to FDT_ERC20Extension ?
I'm  confused with the notion of interface contract, abstract contract...